# Can I break this limit into individual terms?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}  {\frac{x}{x^2+1} +\frac{x}{x^2+2} + ... + \frac{x}{x^2+x} }$$

It seems obvious that the result is zero for each term but in order to break the limit into its individual  parts we must know that every term's limit exists .

Comment: Is x a natural number? This type of questions are usualy solved by the sandwich theorem. (I think it goes to 1 not to 0 by the way)

Comment: this is not possible

Comment: We know a limit distributes over addition in the case that the number of terms you are taking the limit of stays constant.  In your case, as $x$ gets larger, you get more and more terms in your expression, so we can't apply the previous idea here.

Comment: Hint for solving the question in a different way: $\frac{1}{n}>\frac{n}{n^2+k}>\frac{n}{n^2+n}$ for $k<n$ + sandwich theorem.

Comment: Incidentally, at first glance, I was thinking of the technique that actually solves $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x}{x^2+1^2} + \frac{x}{x^2+2^2} + \cdots + \frac{x}{x^2 + x^2} \right) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Here's a simpler example:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n + \frac1n + \cdots + \frac1n$$

where there are $n$ terms in the sum. If we add up the terms, then of course we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1$, even though each term is going to $0$.

The key is that the number of terms grows as $n$ tends to infinity. If there were a fixed number of terms, then you could take the sum of the limits of the terms.

Comment: A great example.  Yes, in isolation, each term tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  But when you add more and more of them up, even though they are each getting smaller at each successive $n$, you are still adding more terms at each successive $n$, and the clear result (after taking the limit) is that, in this example, the act of adding more terms clearly overpowers the diminishing value of each term so that the sum, rather than diminishing itself, tends to a nonzero value.

Comment: For more examples to totally demolish the idea that some people have that one can play with infinity to get around the problem of summing infinitely many terms, see [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10077/1550).

Answer (score 7):

Even if we speak about sequences, it is not possible to treat each term separately. The very simple example is the sequence $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}_{n\text{ factors}}.$$ Each factor tends (separately) to $1$. Is it true that the limit is also $1$? No, this is $\text{e}$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the series of interest can be written as

$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{x}{x^2+2}+\cdots +\frac{x}{x^2+x}=\sum_{k=1}^x \frac{x}{x^2+k}$$

The summand clearly satisfies the bounds

$$\frac{x}{x^2+x}\le\frac{x}{x^2+k}\le \frac{x}{x^2+1}$$

Hence we can assert that

$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+x}\le \sum_{k=1}^x\frac{x}{x^2+k}\le \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$

whereby application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{x}{x^2+2}+\cdots +\frac{x}{x^2+x}\right)=1$$

Comment: At long last, the coveted limit hath been found!

Comment: @AlexLi Now that was funny.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that when $x\to \infty:$ 
$$\frac{x}{x^2+k} \sim \frac{1}{x}, \ \ \ 1\le k \le x$$
Hence: $$L \sim \lim_{x\to\infty} x \cdot \frac{1}{x} = 1.$$